# WP Insert Post function - Insert Post Thumbnail

Tags: php, posts, post-thumbnails

Whilst performing wp_insert_post, how would one insert the post thumbnail. I tried the code below to no avail.

```
$postit = array(
    'post_title' => $itemtitle,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'items',
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'tags_input' => $the_post_id,
    'post_thumbnail' => $itemimage,

);
 $the_post_idit = wp_insert_post( $postit);
```

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Answer (score 1):

you need to first create the post and get the id:

```
$postit = array(
    'post_title' => $itemtitle,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'items',
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'tags_input' => $the_post_id

);

 $the_post_idit = wp_insert_post( $postit);
```

Once you have the post id you can use

```
update_post_meta( $the_post_idit,'_thumbnail_id',$itemimage);
```

just make sure that $itemimage holds the attachment ID.

Comment: Its alright. I found that sending the thumbnail URL was in the end easier

Answer (score 0):

This sends the thumbnail URL as a custom field. It is what I used in the end.

```
$itemimage = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($itemID));

__update_post_meta( $the_post_idit, 'productimage', $itemimage);
```